# var functionName = function() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class

I have a `javascript`class named displayer specifed by an id and an unsigned integer between 1 and 8, and that contains some methods (initialize(), getId() and addObject).
The problem is that when I create a new displayer instance on an object and that I call a method, the console is throwing an error which says "`TypeError: myDisplayer.initialize is not a function`"...

The result is that I am searching on it for too much time and that I still don't see where comes the problem from. Do someone has an idea?

I inserted a snippet so that you can judge by yourself.

Thanks.

```js
function displayer(a, b) {
  if (typeof a == typeof undefined || typeof b == typeof undefined) {
    err_msg = "The constructor provided for displayer which should be displayer(id, size) does not fit.";
    throw {
      name: "Contructor Error",
      level: "Show Stopper",
      message: err_msg,
      htmlMessage: "<span style='color:red;'>" + err_msg + "</span>",
      toString: function() {
        return this.name + ": " + this.message;
      }
    };
  } else {
    if (typeof a == 'string') {
      var id = a;
      return true;
    } else {
      var id = $(a).prop('id');
      return;
    }

    this.getId = function() {
      return id;
    };

    this.initialize = function() {
      $('#' + id).css('background', '#000000');
      $('#' + id).css('color', '#FFFFFF');
      $('#' + id).css('padding', '5px');
      $('#' + id).css('border-width', '2px');
      $('#' + id).css('border-style', 'solid');
      $('#' + id).css('border-radius', '10px');
      $('#' + id).css('border-color', '#555555');
      switch (b) {
        case 1:
          if (screen.availHeight < 600 || screen.availWidth < 800) {
            $('#' + id).hide();
            err_msg = "The selected screen resolution (800x600) oversizes the actual resolution (" + screen.availWidth + "x" + screen.availHeight + ")";
            throw {
              name: "Fit Error",
              level: "Show Stopper",
              message: err_msg,
              htmlMessage: "<span style='color:red'>" + err_msg + "</span>",
              toString: function() {
                return this.name + ": " + this.message;
              }
            };
            return false;
          } else {
            $('#' + id).css('width', '800px');
            $('#' + id).css('height', '600px');
            return true;
          }
          break;
        case 2:
          if (screen.availHeight < 600 || screen.availWidth < 1024) {
            $('#' + id).hide();
            err_msg = "The selected screen resolution (1024x600) oversizes the actual resolution (" + screen.availWidth + "x" + screen.availHeight + ")";
            throw {
              name: "Fit Error",
              level: "Show Stopper",
              message: err_msg,
              htmlMessage: "<span style='color:red'>" + err_msg + "</span>",
              toString: function() {
                return this.name + ": " + this.message;
              }
            };
            return false;
          } else {
            $('#' + id).css('width', '1024px');
            $('#' + id).css('height', '600px');
            return true;
          }
          break;
        case 3:
          if (screen.availHeight < 768 || screen.availWidth < 1024) {
            $('#' + id).hide();
            err_msg = "The selected screen resolution (1024x768) oversizes the actual resolution (" + screen.availWidth + "x" + screen.availHeight + ")";
            throw {
              name: "Fit Error",
              level: "Show Stopper",
              message: err_msg,
              htmlMessage: "<span style='color:red'>" + err_msg + "</span>",
              toString: function() {
                return this.name + ": " + this.message;
              }
            };
            return false;
          } else {
            $('#' + id).css('width', '1024px');
            $('#' + id).css('height', '768px');
            return true;
          }
          break;
        case 4:
          if (screen.availHeight < 864 || screen.availWidth < 1152) {
            $('#' + id).hide();
            err_msg = "The selected screen resolution (1152x864) oversizes the actual resolution (" + screen.availWidth + "x" + screen.availHeight + ")";
            throw {
              name: "Fit Error",
              level: "Show Stopper",
              message: err_msg,
              htmlMessage: "<span style='color:red'>" + err_msg + "</span>",
              toString: function() {
                return this.name + ": " + this.message;
              }
            };
            return false;
          } else {
            $('#' + id).css('width', '1152px');
            $('#' + id).css('height', '864px');
            return true;
          }
          break;
        case 5:
          if (screen.availHeight < 720 || screen.availWidth < 1280) {
            $('#' + id).hide();
            err_msg = "The selected screen resolution (1280x720) oversizes the actual resolution (" + screen.availWidth + "x" + screen.availHeight + ")";
            throw {
              name: "Fit Error",
              level: "Show Stopper",
              message: err_msg,
              htmlMessage: "<span style='color:red'>" + err_msg + "</span>",
              toString: function() {
                return this.name + ": " + this.message;
              }
            };
            return false;
          } else {
            $('#' + id).css('width', '1280px');
            $('#' + id).css('height', '720px');
            return true;
          }
          break;
        case 6:
          if (screen.availHeight < 768 || screen.availWidth < 1280) {
            $('#' + id).hide();
            err_msg = "The selected screen resolution (1280x768) oversizes the actual resolution (" + screen.availWidth + "x" + screen.availHeight + ")";
            throw {
              name: "Fit Error",
              level: "Show Stopper",
              message: err_msg,
              htmlMessage: "<span style='color:red'>" + err_msg + "</span>",
              toString: function() {
                return this.name + ": " + this.message;
              }
            };
            return false;
          } else {
            $('#' + id).css('width', '1280px');
            $('#' + id).css('height', '768px');
            return true;
          }
          break;
        case 7:
          if (screen.availHeight < 800 || screen.availWidth < 1280) {
            $('#' + id).hide();
            err_msg = "The selected screen resolution (1280x800) oversizes the actual resolution (" + screen.availWidth + "x" + screen.availHeight + ")";
            throw {
              name: "Fit Error",
              level: "Show Stopper",
              message: err_msg,
              htmlMessage: "<span style='color:red'>" + err_msg + "</span>",
              toString: function() {
                return this.name + ": " + this.message;
              }
            };
            return false
          } else {
            $('#' + id).css('width', '1280px');
            $('#' + id).css('height', '800px');
            return true;
          }
          break;
        case 8:
          if (screen.availHeight < 1024 || screen.availWidth < 1280) {
            $('#' + id).hide();
            err_msg = "The selected screen resolution (1280x1024) oversizes the actual resolution (" + screen.availWidth + "x" + screen.availHeight + ")";
            throw {
              name: "Fit Error",
              level: "Show Stopper",
              message: err_msg,
              htmlMessage: "<span style='color:red'>" + err_msg + "</span>",
              toString: function() {
                return this.name + ": " + this.message;
              }
            };
            return false;
          } else {
            $('#' + id).css('width', '1280px');
            $('#' + id).css('height', '1024px');
            return true;
          }
          break;
        default:
          $('#' + id).hide();
          err_msg = "The selected screen resolution (" + b + ") isn't recognized by our system. Resolutions go from 1 to 8.";
          throw {
            name: "Syntax Error",
            level: "Show Stopper",
            message: err_msg,
            htmlMessage: "<span style='color:red>" + err_msg + "<span>",
            toString: function() {
              return this.name + ": " + this.message;
            }
          };
          return false;
          break;
      }
    };
    //c = obj id, d = top pos, e = left pos
    this.addObject = function(c, d, e) {
      if (typeof d == typeof 42 && typeof e == typeof 42) {
        $('#' + id).append($('#' + c));
        posTop = $('#' + id).offset().top + d;
        posLeft = $('#' + id).offset().left + e;
        $('#' + c).offset({
          top: posTop,
          left: posLeft
        });
        return true;
      } else {
        err_msg = "The positions given for the addObject(id, posTop, posLeft) method are not numerical.";
        throw {
          name: "Syntax Error",
          level: "Show Stopper",
          message: err_msg,
          htmlMessage: "<span style='color:red'>" + err_msg + "</span>",
          toString: function() {
            return this.name + ": " + this.message;
          }
        };
        return false;
      }
    };
  }
}

function createDisplayer(id, res) {
  var myDisplayer = new displayer(id, res);
  myDisplayer.initialize();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="createDisplayer('anId',1);">Create the displayer</button>
<br/>
<div id="anId"></div>
```

Comment: its init() not initalize

Comment: @VasimVanzara How so? The code clearly states `this.initialize = function() {`…`};`.

Comment: myDisplayer.initialize; is object you can access like this

Comment: @VasimVanzara OP is expecting `myDisplayer.initialize` to be a function. If you run the code you'll see that it's `undefined`.

Comment: I am still trying but didn't get an answer

Comment: @VasimVanzara Please don't fill the comments section with chatter. The question is clearly stated and there is a clear answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're prematurely returning when handling the value of `a`.

```
if (typeof a == 'string') {
  var id = a;
  return true; // remove this
} else {
  var id = $(a).prop('id');
  return; // and this
}
```

It may be useful to you to know *how* I discovered this. A common practice when you believe something should be assigned a given value but it isn't is to put logging statements just before or after the expected assignment.

I placed a `console.log` just before `this.initialize = function() { ...` then noticed that it was never logged. This indicated that the function must be returning before that point.

Comment: No, because: `var myDisplayer = new displayer(id, res); console.log(myDisplayer);` prints: displayer {} and not true or undefined

Comment: @Gavriel [Doesn't matter](https://jsfiddle.net/4L2d0myy/), it still returns the value of `this` at that point.

Comment: what do you mean `this`? Why does it return `this` when `return true` is there? Ah, it's because of the `new displayer(...)`, right?

Comment: @Gavriel You got it.